# Deleting char's in a ansiString

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have this ansiString for example

```
DISC506002000001008100021041511207123051520515308154091550920TN177869-0151J1     36J207 70077       0                 0
```

Trying to extract `TN177869-0151J1`

but the code I am using keeps returning me the whole ansistring.

```
function TForm5.ParseDataPartNumber(Data: AnsiString):ansistring;
var
   ExtraData: Ansistring;
begin
    extraData := data;
    Delete(extraData,76,30);
    Delete(extraData,0,61);
    result:=extraData;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it due to it being an ansistring instead of string? that is throwing me off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are 1 based, so change your 2nd Delete to index 1 instead of 0.

ie:

```
function TForm5.ParseDataPartNumber(Data: AnsiString):ansistring;
var
   ExtraData: Ansistring;
begin
    extraData := data;
    Delete(extraData,77,43);
    Delete(extraData,1,61);
    result:=extraData;
end;
```

Your indexes were wrong too to extract that string.  My answer shows changed values.

Comment: Why not use `Copy()` instead?

Answer (score 9):

Your code is not working because you are passing wrong values in the params of the [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Delete) method. Anyway you can use the [`Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Copy) function instead like so

```
function TForm5.ParseDataPartNumber(const Data: AnsiString): ansistring;
begin
    Result:=Copy(Data, 62,15);
end;
```

Comment: The current accepted answer addresses OP's original question better but from a performance point of view, this is the solution that OP shoud implement. 1 Copy is a magnitude faster than 2 deletes.

Comment: @Lieven It's not so much performance as clarity and simplicity. The perf is a nice consequence.

Comment: True, that makes it even better. OP can have it's cake and eat it too.